# error while importing .java file in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp

I have a `.java` file containing a `public` class. It is located under the 'web pages' folder (not under web-inf folder).

On my jsp page I have imported it as: `<%@ page import="packagename.javafilename;" %>`

When I run jsp file, I get error as:

```
Unable to compile class for jsp.
Only a type can be imported. Packagename.filename resolves to a package
```

Comment: You are missing a `%` at the end of the import directive, like: `<%@ page import="packagename.javafilename" %>`

Comment: Give exact code and exact error. You have probably some typo here. Or to import package, write `<%@ page import="packagename.javafilename.*">`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments there seems to be a  missing % towards the end. Here is the way to import classes in jsp

```
// To import one class
<%@ page import="com.xyz.MyClass" %>
```

OR

```
// To import multiple classes from the com.xyz package
<%@ page import="com.xyz.*" %>
```

Comment: i am sorry it was a typing mistake, i corrected my question now

Comment: what is COM in com.xyz.myclass? My "abc.java" file is located in 'web sites' folder (same place where jsp is located)

Comment: @NachiketKamat Are you still getting the error with typo correction?

Comment: @NachiketKamat Also are you sure packagename.javafilename is a class file. As per coding convention class names generallly start with Uppercase letter but package names are all lowercase. So i am wondering whether javafilename is actually class or a package.

Comment: the answer is as sugegsted by Bhushan but I donot know how to convert .java file into .class file.

Comment: @Nachiket: 'com' is part of the package name. Normally package names consist of several names separated by a dot. 'com' is the commercial domain. Other common domains are 'net' and 'org' or your country code. This is roughly analogous to the domains on the WWW, the main difference being that in package names the order is reversed. An example package is: 'com.acme.killerapp' where 'acme' is the company name and 'killerapp' the name of the application.

Answer (score 1):

From your question things are not very clear.

First of all jsp **cannot access .java** but a **.class file** i.e. you have to keep your code compiled.

Secondly the class should be in the **WEB-INF/classes** folder or a jar in **WEB-INF/lib** folder.

Comment: can you tell me how to convert my ".java" file into ".class" file so that I can then place it in web-inf/classes and run my program

Comment: Seems you are new to web development. I suggest you use eclipse and create a web project in that. It will automatically compile your java files and also you can run in a server via eclipse itself.

Comment: also if you just want to compile java then use javac and please read more about how to develop in java as you are asking the very basic of how to compile.

Comment: compile your java class either from command line or use an IDE such as eclipse

Comment: ok i did it via command line as in:- javac filename.java.. now i have got the filename.class.. i have created new folder called classes under web-inf.. i will place this .class fiile under classes folder and get back to you. thank you so much

Comment: can you tell me what import statement i have to write in my jsp page?

Comment: import statement should be fully qualified class name including package name.

Comment: <%@ page import="packagename.classname;" %> gives an error saying there is no package by name of packagename.. package name is basically what the name was before compiling the .java file.. so this should have been working right?

Comment: packagename is "stemm" and classname is "Stemmer". the netbeans on mouseover of stemm is saying that this package doesnot exist.

Comment: <%@ page import="stemm.Stemmer" %>  also you have to keep the class Stemmer.class under WEB-INF/classes/stemm folder

Comment: Oh I c. Yes I willl try that. Can you cite some reference to these concepts please

Comment: @NachiketKamat If you have compiled your class using javac then place it under WEB-INF\classes\packagename\ directoy. You should have the same directory hierarchy created under classes folder as your package hierarchy is.

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax:

```
<%@ page import="package.filename" %>
```

In the last import, you might need to add a semicolon after the end of the package.filename.
So, if you have like 3 imports, then in the 3rd import line make sure to put a semicolon as:

```
<%@ page import="package.filename;" %>
```

One more thing, make sure that the class files are in WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, then it will take care of compiling files. Or else, in CMD, type:
    javac *.java   to compile all the files present in the directory and then put them in WEB-INF/classes/ folder.

Comment: another thing i have noticed is that netbeans says :- package stemm doesnot exist!

Comment: Well, then directory structure isn't what it should be!
In WEB-INF/classes directory, make sure you have a folder named stemm in which there should be a compiled file Stemmer.class. So, this:
    /WEB-INF/classes/stemm/Stemmer.class